# How to convert date text with javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to convert this

```
Sun Jan 08 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)
```

into

```
2012-01-08
```

with javascript?

Regards

**Edit:**

i was actually working with extjs and didn't know there is a built in way to do this with extjs

so i manage to do this

```
var date = new Date("Sun Jan 08 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)");
console.log(Ext.Date.format(date, 'Y-m-d'));
```

which gives me **2012-01-08**

Comment: There are hundreds of questions on this subject in SO. What have you tried/found? What didn't work?

Comment: See this link: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/javascript_date_and_time.php3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To date contructor you can pass a date string :)

```
var date = new Date("Sun Jan 08 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)");
[ date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1 , date.getDate() + 1 ].join("-");
 //"2012-1-8"
```

Comment: You can, but the only **documented** format for that string doesn't match the format the OP tried. Coincidentally, though, I was testing it on various browsers as you posted your answer, though, and all of them seemed happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no real shortcut, until the 5th edition (a couple of years ago) there was **no** standard date string format supported by JavaScript (`Date` was merely required to correctly parse whatever `toString` output, without the format actually used by either being specified in the standard), and as of the 5th edition, the [format that *is* explicitly supported](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15) for parsing isn't the same as what you've quoted (instead, it's a simplified version of ISO-8601). So you'll have to parse it yourself, using regular expressions and/or brute force ([`String#indexOf`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.7), [`String#substring`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.15), [`String#split`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.14)), or use a library (like [DateJS](http://datejs.com)) to do it for you.

**That said**, every browser I tried was happy to parse it for you just via `new Date`, e.g.:

```
var str = "Sun Jan 08 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)";
var dt = new Date(str);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uziwiv) I tried IE6, IE9, Chrome 15, Opera 11, Firefox 9, Firefox 5, Safari 5, Konquerer 4.7.3, and Midori 0.4.0 (spread across Windows and Linux). So if you're happy with that and you test in your target environments (which I don't **know** are web browsers, JavaScript is used on servers and desktops as well), you may be happy with just doing that.

Comment: i was actually working with extjs and didn't know it has a built in way to do this. var date = new Date("Sun Jan 08 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)"); console.log(Ext.Date.format(date, 'Y-m-d'));  which gives me the answer needed 2012-01-08